# ValueErrors: need more than 3 values to unpackk

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x

the goal of this code is to match `year_link` and `tla_2` and output variables `from_, to, digit, name2, min_value, max_value`. I am using a CSV file, that's where the data is being read from. It is posted here: [Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOEGG.jpg) Unfortunately I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/RM/Desktop/win6.py", line 150, in <module>
for from_,to,digit,name2,min_value,max_value in voltage_envelopes[tla_2]:
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack.
```

-

```
data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
year = raw_input(" ")
location=raw_input(" ")
for row in data:
    year_link, from_,to,digit,name2,tla_2,min_value,max_value,last_bus = row[7:16]
    year_link = year
    tla_2=location
    if year_link not in mydict:
        mydict[year_link]={}

    voltage_envelopes=mydict[year_link]

    if tla_2 not in voltage_envelopes:
        voltage_envelopes[tla_2]=[]

    voltage_envelopes[tla_2].append((from_,to,digit,name2,min_value,max_value))

if year_link in mydict and tla_2 in mydict[year_link]:
     voltage_envelopes=mydict[year_link]

     for from_,to,digit,name2,min_value,max_value in voltage_envelopes[tla_2]:
         from_=int(from_)
         to=int(to)
         min_value=float(min_value)
         max_value=float(max_value)
         digit=int(digit)

         output = 'From Bus #: {}\tTo Bus #: {}\t Area Station: {}\t VMIN: {} pu\tVMAX: {} pu\t' 
         print(output.format(from_, to,name2, min_value, max_value))
         print("\n")

        #_c=psspy.getdefaultchar()
        #_i=psspy.getdefaultint()
        #_f=psspy.getdefaultreal()
        #psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%d'% digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
else:
    exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are appending a 6-element tuple to an empty list, which results in a list of just one element. This results in the unpacking error since Python is expecting 6 element sequence. One thing you can do is to extend the list with another list of the 6 elements.

Change

`voltage_envelopes[tla_2].append((from_,to,digit,name2,min_value,max_value))`

to

`voltage_envelopes[tla_2].extend([from_,to,digit,name2,min_value,max_value])`

Comment: I received the same result

Comment: any other ideas

Comment: Can you provide some of your data as a csv file?

Comment: I attached the csv sheet. its labeled Excel Sheet in the beginning

Comment: I will need a workable excel sheet. I cannot run the code on a jpg file.

Comment: I cant attach excel file. Can I? Can I email you?

Comment: You can upload the file on dropbox or Google drive or any other file hosting service and share the link in the question. This way, it will be easier for the whole stackOverflow community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack.

Your Example code is working as expected, **no ValueError**!
Examining your code it's impossible to get such a Error as you assign **6** Values and unpack **6** Values:

```
voltage_envelopes[tla_2].
    append((from_,to,digit,name2,min_value,max_value))
...
        for from_,to,digit,name2,min_value,max_value in voltage_envelopes[tla_2]:
```

I assume the shown Traceback **is not** from the Example code shown in the Question!

---

Change the following to **catch** the error-prone Line of Data:

```
        #for from_, to, digit, name2, min_value, max_value in voltage_envelopes[tla_2]:
        for voltage in voltage_envelopes[tla_2]:
            if len(voltage) == 6:
                from_, to, digit, name2, min_value, max_value = voltage 
                ...
            else:
                print('[FAIL] Missing Data in "voltage"! Got {} values={} need 6 values!'.format(len(voltage), voltage))
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***